# Vacuum thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum

Consider a large space of ultra high vacuum space like:
10-12 hPa and 26500 molecules per cm³,

then from a thermodynamic perspective,
Is this vacuum space a microscopic system or macroscopic system ?
Do the laws of thermodynamics, that is more relevant to macroscopic systems, apply well in a high or ultra high vacuum system ?

Answer (score 1):

If we have reasons to believe that system is an equilibrium (e.g., the high vacuum is contained in a vessel, and is left to itself for a long time), then the relative errors in thermodynamic quantities are of the order of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}},$$
as treated in any good statistical physics textbook.

These cannot be dismissed outright, as is usual in the case where $N\sim N_A$, but it seems that thermodynamic treatment suffices for many situations. It is hard to say more on the basis of what is given in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes still macroscopic. Nice article and expanations are given in

[From Microscopic to Macroscopic Behavior](https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9375.pdf)

They even state N>100 suffices, see 1.4